# Do <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapte> programatically

Tags: spring-integration

i try to change from xml to programatically configuration one example from spring-boot integration which is [SftpInboundReceiveSample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/sftp/SftpInboundReceiveSample.java)

These are my configurations :
SftpPoller

```
@Configuration
public class SftpPoller{

@Autowired
SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sFtpInboundFileSynchronizer;

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "receiveChannel",poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "1000",maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
MessageSource<File> pollFtpForFiles() {

    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sFtpInboundFileSynchronizer);
    messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File("local-dir"));
    messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);

    return messageSource;
}
@Bean
PollableChannel receiveChannel() {return new QueueChannel();}
}
```

FtpConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("META-INF/spring/integration/SftpSampleCommon.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class SftpConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("serverPort")
    String serverPort;

    @Value("${privateKeyfile}")
    Resource privateKeyfile;
    ...

    @Bean
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPrivateKey(privateKeyfile);
        factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(passphrase);
        .....
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    CachingSessionFactory cachingSessionFactory(DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory) {
        return new CachingSessionFactory(defaultSftpSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer(CachingSessionFactory cachingSessionFactory) {
        final SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(cachingSessionFactory);
        sftpInboundFileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("remote-dir");
        sftpInboundFileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        return sftpInboundFileSynchronizer;
    }
}
```

SftpInboundReceiveSample.java

```
@Test
public void runDemo() {
    //load context
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = 
       new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SftpConfiguration.class, SftpPoller.class);
    ....

    try{
        PollableChannel localFileChannel = 
                context.getBean("receiveChannel", PollableChannel.class);
        ....

        // cant find SourcePollingChannelAdapter
        SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter =
                context.getBean(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class); -

        adapter.start();
        ....
}
```

Question :

1. Where can i find `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` or should I look for different 'PollingChannelAdapter' ?
2. Is it possible to move all configurations inside xml (except SftpSampleCommon.xml) to POJO? and how ?

thank you for any help and assistance.

Comment: thank you @slawalata for showing the code, it's working! I think it's one of the few implementations xml-free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to add `@EnableIntegration` on the `@Configuration`. That's is the main annotation to bootstrap Spring Integration infrastructure.
2. The `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` doesn't exist because of the  `@EnableIntegration` absence.
3. Looks like you already did everything in the Java Config! :-)
4. You even can move that `SftpSampleCommon.xml` to the Java Config as well.

Please, read more about Spring Integration [Annotation Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations) and pay attention to the Spring Integration [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) project.

Comment: 1. thank you for showing what i have missed. 2. i will move `SftpSampleCommon.xml` to Java Config to learn more about spring 3. Currently I am building prototype to use `FtpInbound` with with `SpringIntegrationFlow` to learn how it works. many thanks.